# Jquery UI Accordion in sidebar menu lags

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using the Accordion from the jQuery UI library (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) as a sidebar. When I mouseover from top to bottom on the sidebar, the accordion expands somewhat fine. But when I mouseover from bottom to top onto an item that is supposed to expand, it does not until i pass the item (in the example "Bags"). Here's the page: (http://ignitepixels.com/seba)

Here's the jquery:

```
$( "ul#cats" ).accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        header: "li",
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false, 
        active: false
});
```

Anyone have any idea why I am getting this lag? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup for the UL is not well formed. You can't throw in DIVs between LIs and not expect browsers to behave like they're buzzed. Can you do anything else? E.g. change UL to a DIV, remove LI tags, keep A tags, keep DIV tags; then set `header:"div#cats a"`.

Comment: Good point. I don't even know why I didn't suspect that yet. I will change that right now and see if I can't get better results

Comment: Alright, now I've normalized the code to be: ul#cats > li.sidebar_header + li.sidebar_content, etc. Still no dice. Any other suggestions?

Comment: still not good :) jquery-ui accordion expects one tag for the title, and one for the content; see their docs > overview: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/; if you use firebug, you'll see that every 2nd of your LI's currently is considered to be content box for the LI that's preceding it (even LI's are set to display:none). I suggest you change UL to DIV, and do A, DIV, A, DIV, A, DIV, ... Alternatively, A's can be H1-7 or any other tag (even DIV), but it must be distinguishable from content boxes. Aside from that, I don't have any other suggestion.

Comment: Changed. Still have the laggy problem. It seems to happen most on the first mouseover of each .sidebar_header

Comment: hm. I tried to isolate this thing by copying your markup and css and just the js that matters - and I'm seeing it behave oddly even without any other unrelated things. Then I wondered if it's maybe because some of your content div's are empty, so I replaced empty ones with some samples, and the accordion suddenly behaves the way it's supposed to! So, now I'm pretty sure that's the problem. However, in your case, obviously it will be a problem, since you can't just make up items in empty categories. So, try this: add sidebar_header just to those A tags that relate to non-empty DIV's.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you might need to get rid of accordion, and just use jQuery.hover with maybe animate, or similar

Comment: Good looking out! It looks like that was the ticket. I just removed all the .sidebar_header classes from the non drop down items, fixed up my css a little, and removed the empty divs and its super smooth now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: maybe you also want to remove the little arrows from top-menu items that have no child items. It makes me feel that I have to wait for those to open, and they never do.

Comment: I don't like how the expanded menu collapses when you hover from a subitem back to the related top-menu item. e.g: hover over "bags", wait for it to open, hover over "backpacks", hover over "bags" again. The bags closes, where I feel it should be left open; I couldn't figure out what's causing this (unless it's the accordion itself).